# $.get not returning any data in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, get

I'm using JQuery's $.get function to fetch a twitter feed and display it on my site. I have no idea why it seems to not be getting any data (i.e. code inside function(d) { ... } doesn't get called). It works fine in everything else I've tried. I have also used this code before with no problems, the only thing I can think of is that it is running through https.

(Note that for the example I've removed the twitter user id from the feed url)

JS:

```
    $.get('proxy.php?url=http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/999999999.rss', function(d) {    
        $(d).find('item').each(function() {
            var theItem = $(this);
            var title = theItem.find('title').text();


            var date = new Date(theItem.find('pubDate').text());
            var alink = theItem.find('link').text();

            // code ommitted (inserts tweet into page)
        });
  });
```

proxy.php:

```
<?php
    // PHP Proxy
    // Loads a XML from any location. Used with Flash/Flex apps to bypass security restrictions
    // Author: Paulo Fierro
    // January 29, 2006
    // usage: proxy.php?url=http://mysite.com/myxml.xml

    $session = curl_init($_GET['url']);                    // Open the Curl session
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);          // Don't return HTTP headers
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   // Do return the contents of the call
    $xml = curl_exec($session);                            // Make the call

    $seconds_to_cache = 300; // five mins (60 * 5)
    $ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $seconds_to_cache) . " GMT";
    header("Expires: $ts");
    header("Pragma: cache");
    header("Cache-Control: maxage=$seconds_to_cache");
    //header("Content-Type: text/xml");   // Set the content type appropriately
    header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml");
    echo $xml;        // Spit out the xml
    curl_close($session); // And close the session
?>
```

Any ideas / help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: At which point does it break? Does the script manage to get any data? Do you ger any errors?

Comment: shouldn't it be `"Expires: ".$ts` and `"Cache-Control: maxage=".$seconds_to_cache`?

Comment: The PHP script seems to be working fine, I did change those variables as you suggested to be safe, but when the url is physically accessed in the address bar it renders the feed as expected, and it works fine in other browsers. I don't get any JS errors, it just fails silently. If I put an alert inside the function (i.e. before the $(d).find line), it doesn't get displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. IE needs the content type to be set to text/xml. I changed the proxy.php script:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
```

and that was all I needed.

Comment: I am seeing a similiar issue. did you just put that line in the php file? How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I think I know what is going on.  By default the `$.get()` method has a return content type of `text/html`.  You are getting XML data, and immediately passing it into the `jQuery` function for evaluation.  All the browsers other than IE will allow you to create those XML nodes, but if IE sees an element type it does not recognize, it will fail.

It seems the solution to your problem is to explicitly say you are expecting XML from the response.  See [this example](http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/) for how to go about this.

EDIT 2:

In further reading I've seen that there is mixed luck in getting IE to interpret the XML correctly even with the example I provided above.  If you are still having problems, you can always try converting your XML to JSON on the server (see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml2jsonphp/ for a working `class` that accomplishes this).  You'll be able to consistently work with JSON on the client side, but you will need to update your `success` data processing function accordingly.

Original Answer:

I would be willing to guess that the problem is IE is very happy to cache URLs.  I recommend appending an additional, unused, but randomly generated query string parameter to get around this.

```
$.get('proxy.php?url=http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/999999999.rss&rand=' + Math.floor(Math.random()*999999), function() { //omitted });
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a go but it gave me the same results (I am using the same technique on the JS file too, because I'm paranoid)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, and you're right -- you see it mostly in IE. This is the fix:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
  });
});
```

Apply that property on your page before you do the $.get() call, and it will eliminate the issue, more than likely.